# Java not get all printer network on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, printers

Code working printer install local not working printer share or printer server.
Please help, I want get all printer connect. 
Thanks all.

```
 import javax.print.*;

class Test {

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        System.out.println("Number of print services: " + printServices.length);

        for (PrintService printer : printServices)
            System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can Linux itself find the printers?

Comment: Can find the printers install local, but don't can find the printers connect another computer. Please help

Comment: I think that you need to configure your Ubuntu system so that it can find the remote printers.  Then Java will be able to see them.  But configuring Ubuntu printers is a system admin problem, not a programming problem.  Ask on one of the stackexchange sites ....